AWS Lambda cant get from ElastiCache Memcached
I have a Lambda function that needs to access a serverless ElastiCache Memcached instance.
The Lambda is configured with the correct IAM permissions, network settings, and security group configuration. However, when I run a Get command from the Lambda, it just hangs.
The Lambda code looks like this:
import os
from pymemcache.client import base
import json

# Get the ElastiCache Memcached endpoint from environment variables
MEMCACHED_ENDPOINT = os.getenv('MEMCACHED_ENDPOINT')
MEMCACHED_ENDPOINT = MEMCACHED_ENDPOINT + ":11211"

if not MEMCACHED_ENDPOINT:
    raise ValueError("MEMCACHED_ENDPOINT environment variable not set")

# Try splitting and validate the format of MEMCACHED_ENDPOINT

try:
    endpoint_parts = MEMCACHED_ENDPOINT.split(":")
    if len(endpoint_parts) != 2:
        raise ValueError("MEMCACHED_ENDPOINT format is incorrect, should be 'host:port'")
    memcached_host = endpoint_parts[0]
    memcached_port = int(endpoint_parts[1])
except Exception as e:
    raise ValueError(f"Error parsing MEMCACHED_ENDPOINT: {str(e)}")

# Create a client to connect to Memcached
client = base.Client((memcached_host, memcached_port))

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("lambda handler starts")
    try:
        # Test 1: Add a new item (fails if key already exists)
        response_add = client.add('test_key', 'test_value')
        add_message = f"Add operation successful: {response_add}"
        print("TEST 1 DONE: Add")

        # Test 2: Set (upsert) an item (if it exists, update; if not, create)
        client.set('test_key', 'updated_value')
        set_message = "Set operation successful."
        print("TEST 2 DONE: Set")
        
        # Test 3: Put (same as set, used interchangeably here)
        client.set('test_key_put', 'put_value')
        put_value = client.get('test_key_put')
        put_message = f"Put operation successful, value retrieved: {put_value.decode('utf-8')}"
        print("TEST 3 DONE: Put")

        # Test 4: Get the value of the key
        value = client.get('test_key')
        get_message = f"Get operation successful, value retrieved: {value.decode('utf-8')}"
        print("TEST 4 DONE: Get")



        # Return a response summarizing all operations
        return {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'body': json.dumps({
                'add_message': add_message,
                'set_message': set_message,
                'get_message': get_message,
                'put_message': put_message
            })
        }

    except Exception as e:
        return {
            'statusCode': 500,
            'body': f"Error occurred: {str(e)}"
        }

The issue arises when the Lambda reaches the Put operation; it hangs and continues running until the Lambda times out. I cannot confirm if the Add and Set operations are successful; I suspect they may not be.
Why is this happening? I thought it could be a KMS encryption problem, so I created a new cache with a customer-managed key and included the Lambda role to have full access to the key. However, I am still encountering the same issue. Has anyone seen this before? The version of the ElastiCache engine is 1.6.22.

Timeout is typically caused by lack of network route. It's never about permissions e.g. on a KMS key. You said that your network settings and security group configuration are correct but didn't provide them. You should probably include them.

I know the network is okay, i set up an ec2 instance in the same subnets as the Lambda, the SG on the Elasticache allows all inbound from the VPC. in the instance i can telnet the endpoint such
sh-5.2$ telnet moli-closedsanking-ec-yyyyyy.serverless.apse2.cache.amazonaws.com 11211 Trying 172.24.9.169... Connected to moli-closedsanking-ec-yyyyyy.serverless.apse2.cache.amazonaws.com. Escape character is '^]'. 

You mentioned KMS. I don't see anything KMS-related in your code but wonder if you need access to the KMS service e.g. via KMS VPC endpoint.

Can you try with timeout, connect_timeout and no_delay parameters to the client and provide the results? Your Memcached is with tls?
